# db2 sql IN OR performance

Tags: sql, performance, select, db2, where-clause

in DB2 query, what is the fastest between:

1)
SELECT A, B, C from MY_TABLE where Z = 'VAL1' OR Z = 'VAL2' OR Z = 'VAL3';

2)
SELECT A, B, C from MY_TABLE where Z IN ('VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3');

Comment: What have you observed is happening?

Comment: one would hope they are the same thing

Comment: I just finished testing it on very large structures and it seems that in my case the IN(x, y, z) is way faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used db2 but if you're seeing better performance with the `IN`, it might be optimizing your query to do something like this under the hood:

```
SELECT
    A, B, C
FROM
    MY_TABLE m
JOIN
    (VALUES 'VAL1','VAL2','VAL3') AS v(Value)
    ON
    m.Z = v.Value
```

Which I think would be more efficient than the three OR lookups. Do you have any indexes on `Z`?